# MySQL: Get how many rows were changed from and changed to

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to solve a problem that I can’t figure out. Basically what I have is a database with thousands of records. Then I want to select e.g. 500 fruit and change all those 500 fruit records to “Orange”. Then I want to save how many records I changed to “Orange” and also how many times of each fruit was changed. If a previous fruit was changed to “Orange” then it is a -1 for that fruit but +1 for Orange. What would be an efficient way to do this with many fruits and records?

```
Fruit column (change to ->) 

Apple   ->  Orange
Peach   ->  Orange
Banana  ->  Strawberry
Orange  ->  Orange
Apple   ->  Banana

Fruit       Added   Removed
Orange        2        0
Strawberry    1        0
Apple         0        2
Banana        1        1
```

Comment: Whats your attempt to solve this?

Comment: I thought of looping through every single record but realized it was going to be kind of slow...

Comment: Create a table with columns : Fruit       Added   Removed
and add trigger to your existing table

Comment: Read up on triggers.

Comment: Whats the structure of your table? Id | fruit | count ?